# Custom Partitioning & Sorting in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to apply custom partitioning & sorting on a Spark Dataframe. [From what I understood so far, it's not possible without going via RDD & conversion between RDD & Dataframe has a cost]. My plan is to use repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions method on PairRDD. Is there any better way to doing it?

While trying to use 'repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions', below is the problem I am facing:

The dataframe I have is,

```
val df = dataset.select(AbstractRecordProvider
      .getKeyUDF(sparkArguments.getDatasetArguments)
        (col(hashKeyName), lit(null)).as("key"), to_json(struct(dataset.columns.map(col): _*)).as("value"))
```

getKeyUDF returns 'Byte[Array]' & to_json returns 'String', so basically by schema for df should look like

```
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I have custom Ordering defined as ::

`class LexicographicalOrdering extends Ordering[Array[Byte]]`

I have a custom Partitioner defined as ::

`class XXHashRangeBasedPartitioner(partitions: Int) extends Partitioner`

and I am setting up the custom Ordering as an implicit Ordering for Array[Byte]

`implicit val ordering: Ordering[Array[Byte]] = new LexicographicalOrdering`.

The challenge I am facing is with applying the '[repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/OrderedRDDFunctions.html)'. I understand repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions can only be applied to PairRDD. However,

```
val pairRDD = df.rdd.map(record => (record.get(0),record.get(1))).repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new XXHashRangeBasedPartitioner(10))
```

leads to error

`error: value repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Any)]`.

I think I should get the RDD to be of type RDD[(Array[Byte], String)] instead of RDD[(Any, Any)], since '[repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/OrderedRDDFunctions.html)' mentions 'They will work with any key type K that has an implicit Ordering[K] in scope.' and I have an implicit Ordering[Array[Byte]].

How can I transform RDD[(Any, Any)] to RDD[Array[Byte], String] or get RDD[Array[Byte], String] in the first place from the dataframe I have.

== EDIT ==

I was able to typecast using 'asInstanceOf'

```
val partitionedDf = df.rdd.map(record => (record.get(0).asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]],record.get(1).asInstanceOf[String])).repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new XXHashRangeBasedPartitioner(sparkArguments.getPartitionConfigurationArguments.getNumberOfPartitions))
```

Is there a better or more efficient way to achieving 'custom partitioning & sorting' than what I am doing above?